# управляющий символ или управляющая последовательность для нажатия стрелок в bios

Tags: python, linux, serial, ascii, pyserial

Итак, хочу написать скрипт, который позволит настраивать bios через COM порт, используя библиотеку pyserial. Устройство уже соединено с компом, на котором стоит linux. Дальше нужно передать в COM порт управляющие символы, чтобы управлять настройкой в меню биоса. Как это работает сейчас?

from serial import Serial

ser = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)

ser.write(chr(27).encode()) # Здесь я "нажимаю" Esc, указав код 27 для соответствующего управляющего
символа - https://xn----7sbbaqhlkm9ah9aiq.net/news-new/kodi-ascii-simvolov.html

Теперь мне нужно переходить из меню в меню или прыгать со строки на строку. Для этого нужно "нажимать" стрелки влево-вправо-вверх-вниз, однако соответствующего управляющего символа в таблице под это дело нет.

Знаете ли вы, что такое нужно записать в последовательный порт, чтобы на другом конце провода нажалась стрелка? Я подозреваю, что это либо какой-то символ, либо управляющая последовательность.

Следует отметить, что ser.write('^[[C'.encode()) (это у меня выводится на экран при нажатии на стрелку в linux) не сработало, также как не сработало ser.write('\u2192'.encode()) (символ стрелки в юникоде). Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, я работаю на linux, так что константы windows мне не помогут. Я все равно попробовал ввести те коды, но не сработало

Comment: Биос не работает на линукс,  так что попробуйте константы виндовс

Comment: В BIOS есть выбор типа терминала, вот его последовательности и используй. (Часто это vt100 или ANSI)

Comment: Почитайте там: https://superuser.com/questions/1148731/how-to-read-write-all-bios-settings-from-linux-cli